# Taskbar hangs when a program is not responding

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar

My taskbar hangs when a program is not responding.

Is there any solution to the problem above? I'm using Windows XP, but the problem will probably still exist on Windows 7 and Vista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this when a particular app hangs, or any app? If "any" can you give examples of some that you have seen the problem with?

This is usually specific to Windows Explorer, or something that is interacting with is such as some shell extensions, stops responding for a time or permanently because the task bar is managed (at least in XP and Vista, so I assume by 7 too) by Explorer.

One thing you can do to reduce the occurrences of one explorer object causing others to stop responding when it does is to select "launch folder windows in separate processes" in the advanced folder options accessible from the options item in the tools menu of any explorer Window (Vista hides menus by default, 7 may too or it may be in a difference place entirely, press <kbd>T</kbd> while holding <kbd>Atl</kbd> to get to the Tools menu in Explorer in Vista).

Comment: specifically visual studio 2008 and virtual box